# Convert between case classes with same structure

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, shapeless

I have two identical case classes, let's say

```
case class JsonOutput(
  creationDate: ZonedDateTime,
  updateDate: ZonedDateTime,
  doctorName: String,
  patientName: String,
  userName: String
)
```

and

```
case class DbOutput(
  creationDate: ZonedDateTime,
  updateDate: ZonedDateTime,
  doctorName: String,
  patientName: String,
  userName: String
)
```

which structurally are the same, but doesn't have some relation (and their similarity might be changed in the future)

I want to convert `DbOutput` type which I get from database to `JsonOutput`, which later I'll use for convertion (by Play Json) like

```
//fullCase is of type JsonOutput
Ok(Json.obj("case" -> fullCase))
```

*How I would do this?*

**Note:**

And what to do in case of nested case class structure:

```
case class GeneralInfo(number: Int)

// Nested case class structure
case class JsonOneOutput(text: String)
case class JsonThreeOutput(meta: JsonOneOutput, info: GeneralInfo)

// Nested case class structure    
case class DbOneOutput(text: String)
case class DbThreeOutput(meta: DbOneOutput, info: GeneralInfo)
```

where I again have to convert `DbOutput` to `JsonOutput` (and all types are the same, except some leaf node type like `DbOneOutput` and `JsonOneOutput`, which can be at deep level)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to do this with shapeless so I would suggest you take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes). A example of how this could be achieved is:

```
import shapeless.Generic

object FooBar {

  case class Foo(a: String, b: Int, c: String)
  case class Bar(x: String, y: Int, z: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val genFoo = Generic[Foo]
    val genBar = Generic[Bar]

    println(genBar.from(genFoo.to(Foo("foobar", 5, "barfoo"))))
  }

}
```

Comment: I saw this docs, but how to do this with multiple `String` types? It looks like a have to use `LabelledGeneric`, but I didn't understand how to utilize that.